# Could not determine storage version; a valid storage connection or a version hint is required

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

This is proving to be my least favorite error message that I've ever encountered as it has reared its head multiple times as of late and worse, doesn't really seem to speak to what is at issue.

```
Could not determine storage version; a valid storage connection or a version hint is required.
```

Now, this has actually appeared so far 3 times: production db server (console app triggering it), production web server (asp.net web forms app), and development web server (asp.net web forms app). Would probably impact db server too, but because the console app is about sending emails to users, I didn't include it in that location.

So first was the production db server. I did a ton of searching around for fixes to this message and the one thing that fixed it was going to the machine.config files and stripping out the "extra" dbfactories node ("extra" in that I believe it was there first, but IBM DB2 driver added one to place itself in). Production web server, exact same case (and it occurred after it was truly live and they installed the DB2 driver. Would've been some seriously fun times had I not seen it with the database already).

So when we built the dev server, I started running into this message again as soon as a context.set.Where call was being executed against the main dbcontext. The DB2 driver is installed in this environment as well, however, when I look at the machine.config files, there's only one dbfactory node (and it doesn't include a reference to the DB2 driver).

Now, one caveat worth mentioning is that for connection strings, we're storing them in environmental variables (keeps it out of the web.config, *should* make migration to other instances easier, etc). However, this works perfectly fine in production and my local machine. In fact, I updated my local machine's environmental variables to use the connection string for the dev database and it loads fine.

Oh, and entity framework is 6.1.3. I use database first (I guess? I really just have DbContext/DbSet against classes) so there's no edmx or whatever file that handles database configuration.

Based on all of this, I feel like it is yet again another oddball configuration item, but from what I can tell I've exhausted all of the items I've found online to triage it. Is there a way to find out what the true error is (like how the two production servers it was due to more than one dbfactory collection)?

Comment: Fwiw (2012): https://hgminerva.wordpress.com/2012/03/19/how-to-solve-the-could-not-determine-storage-version-a-valid-storage-connection-or-a-version-hint-is-required-in-microsoft-ligthswitch/

Comment: 2014: http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/02/moving-from-entity-framework-5-to-entity-framework-6-and-back-or-could-not-determine-storage-version/

Comment: Connection string is fine; works when running locally from my work machine (just not on dev server). Both configured with the same environment variables. Don't have a lsml file either, unfortunately.

Comment: Forgot about this one, but I've looked at this one as well, but I don't have migrations in the databases (prod or dev).

Answer (score -1):

work for me EF.5
delete .edmx then add it again